# Can someone explain why my Python plot won't show anything?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my code:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import numpy as np

#variables
n = 50

#integral
denominator = integrate.quad(lambda S: math.exp(-10*S)*(10*S**n),0,300)

#function
S = np.linspace(0,300,0.01)
y_i = (np.exp(-10*S)*(10*S**n))/denominator[0]

plt.plot(S,y_i)
```

I realise it's a very simplistic question. I'm trying to integrate the denominator across 0 and 300, and then plot the function y_i with the definite integral as the denominator of y_i. However when I plot it, the graph shown appears empty, when I am expecting a probability distribution, peaking at 5.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need `plt.show()` at the end of your code snippet. Secondly and more importantly, you misused `np.linspace`. Run it in interactive mode gives:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> S = np.linspace(0,300,0.01)
>>> S
array([], dtype=float64)
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) , the third argument, if not specified by name, is taken as the number of samples to generate. In this case, none (or a more disturbing interpretation is that you only want 0.01 sample). If by that last `0.01` in that line, you mean the step size, maybe you are looking for something like `S = np.linspace(0,300,int(300.0/0.01))` or as **@kameranis** pointed out: `S = np.arange(0, 300, 0.01)`.

Resulting figure:

[image]

Comment: A better use would be `S = np.arange(0, 300, 0.01)`

Comment: Thanks, I know it was basic but that helps, appreciated.